# Window moving and resizing interferes with MsgWaitForMultipleObjects

Tags: winapi, event-handling, message-loop

I have an application that message-loops using MsgWaitForMultipleObjects to catch additional events while pumping ui messages. It seems that as soon as a window is being moved or resized, DefWindowProc begins it's own message loop until the mouse is being released. This situation prevents from the outer loop to catch the additional messages in the meantime.

I'd hate to multi-thread the application just because of this. Is there any other way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

MsgWaitForMultipleObjects has very few uses in a traditional multi threaded program. It has some use in Games - where traditional non client frame elements are omitted and APIs like "MessageBox" and "DoDragDrop" are avoided...

Usually it finds its best use in "UI worker" threads that don't host visible windows, but use the message queue as an inter thread messaging system and also need to wait on kernel handles.

In your case, making a second thread does not seem avoidable. Ironically, PostThreadMessage + MsgWaitForMultipleObjects will probably be the easiest way to set up a reliable communication mechanism between the GUI thread and your "ui" worker thread.

Answer (score 0):

There are several additional places in the Windows API that will enter their own message loop.  If you need to continue handling your messages during these times then you'll need a separate thread.